# How can I change the timeout threshold in SBT dependency resolution?

Tags: scala, dependencies, sbt

I have a project using sbt 0.13 that is set up to first try a corporate proxy repository for dependencies, followed by maven and other public repos.

When the proxy repo is not available (because I'm out of office, not on a VPN, whatever), sbt takes around two minutes to time out and fall back to the other repositories. This makes resolution of new dependencies *extremely* slow.

Is there any way to reduce this timeout threshold, so that sbt will only try to reach a repository for five seconds before giving up?